# LTspice simulation of AD8421 instrumentation amplifier giving incorrect output voltages

Tags: ltspice, instrumentation-amplifier

I am trying to run a simple simulation of an instrumentation amplifier (AD8421, model from [here](http://www.analog.com/en/design-center/simulation-models/spice-models.html)) running on a single supply, but the output does not seem to be correct. The screenshot below shows the schematic and simulation output. I am setting both the common mode voltage and in-amp reference voltage to 2.5 V, or half the supply voltage of 5 V. The in-amp gain is set to 100, and the input differential voltage steps from -5 mV to +5 mV. Therefore, I expect my output voltage to go from 2 V to 3 V, and be linear. This is not what I see.

I have checked that this is a good operating configuration for the AD8421 using the tool [here](http://www.analog.com/designtools/en/diamond/#difL=-0.005&difR=0.005&difSl=-0.005&gain=100&l=2.5&pr=AD8421&r=2.5&sl=2.5&tab=1&ty=1&vn=0&vp=5&vr=2.5). Is there an error with my simulation configuration, or something else wrong?

[image]

**EDIT:** Per the suggestion in the comments, upping the supply voltage to 10 V (and Vcm and Vref to 5 V) gives the correct output.

Comment: Something seems to wrong with the model . Verify updates. Or try again with Vdd=10V down to 5V . There is not enough gain to work on your model at the minimum of 5V. Strange

Comment: Perhaps try reducing the step speed?

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist upping the supply voltage to 10 V (and Vcm and Vref to 5 V) appears to solve the issue. I get the correct output.

Comment: Try 5.5V or near to find the model limit for Vt bias